# Hotmail can not properly read email with ! in url

Tags: email, url, hotmail, hashbang

I have a single page app, which has URLs like `http://example.com/#!something/something/`. The problem is that when I send email containing link to such url, hotmail users get them wrong (I have noticed it only in hotmail, everyone else is good).

The `!` is encoded to `%21` which makes the url wrong: `http://example.com/#%21something/something/`

Any ideas what can be done except rewriting my app :-). I am using [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) to send email, but I highly doubt that this is relevant.

Answer (score 4):

According to RFC3986, the `"!"` character is valid in the fragment (`#...`) component of URIs, so it should not get encoded using percent-encoding. In this sense, this seems to be an outlook.com bug.

One workaround is to use plain-text emails: based on my tests, outlook.com encodes `!`'s HTML email links only and plain-text emails are safe.

The real solution, however, is to do your own normalization in the client-side code. URL cracking and normalization is a really tricky business, so I'd expect issues with other email clients, too. Running JavaScript `decodeUriComponent()` against `window.location.hash` should give you the unencoded `"#!/something/something"` version regardless whether the exclamation mark was encoded or not. I understand this calls for modifying the web application that you wanted to avoid, but to my best knowledge this is the way to go.